# Adding column values ​across all rows

Tags: sql

Let's suppose I have this table:

```
+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| id | name  | rating1 | rating2 | rating3 |
+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | joao  |       9 |      10 |      10 |
|  2 | joao  |       9 |       9 |       9 |
|  3 | jaoo  |       8 |       9 |       9 |
|  4 | maria |       5 |       6 |       9 |
|  5 | maria |       2 |       5 |       8 |
+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

How can I run the following process in SQL?

```
Joao: (9+10+10+9+9+9+8+9+9 / 3) / 3 = 9,11 avg
Maria: (5+6+9+2+5+8 / 3) / 2 = 5,83 avg
```

expected out:

```
+-------+------------+
| name  | avg_rating |
+-------+------------+
| joao  |       9,11 |
| maria |       5,83 |
+-------+------------+
```

i tried the following:

```
SELECT name, rating1+rating2+rating3 FROM registers WHERE rating1 IS NOT NULL AND rating1 > 0 GROUP BY name
```

but looks like this SQL only sum one line

Comment: Please tag RDBMS that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sum()`:

```
SELECT name, SUM(rating1+rating2+rating3) / (COUNT(*) * 3)
FROM registers
WHERE rating1 IS NOT NULL AND rating1 > 0
GROUP BY name;
```